# Where are outlets and actions stored in codes in Objective C?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I understand that in Objective C we can link buttons and actions together using the interface builder, but the connection must be physically stored in the source code somewhere. I just want to know where is the exact location so I can view it in source code. Not that I am going to manipulate it in anyway I just want to know where they are stored.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually there is no linkage, which is why people often mess this up. The xib/storyboard has some *names*. And the code has some *names*. But only when the nib loads during runtime is an attempt made to match them up. If they don't match (and it is perfectly possible for them not to match), you can crash.

Answer (score 1):

All the objects and relationships are stored inside the interface builder files like xib or storyboard in the XML format. Those files are parsed during the runtime and the corresponding objects are instantiated along with their relationships. So there is no objective-c code you can find in any of your files. It's all in XML.

Comment: For completeness: the XML is transformed into a binary format (the "nib") as part of compilation.